# Изменить поле в запросе Laravel

Tags: laravel

Записывают в базу таким способом

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $inivation = Inivation::create($request->all());
}
```

Как отредактировать или добавить значение из $request ?
К примеру в $request нет поля user_id ,а мне нужно его добавить и записать в таблицу

Comment: если пользователь от которого что-то добавляется авторизован то используйте стандартный метод `Auth::id()` получите ID авторизованного пользователя

Comment: Я имею ввиду как редактировать код чтоб можно было изменить или дописать одно поле?

Comment: создайте переменную, в нее положите результат `$request->all()`, после в созданную переменную добавляйте нужные вам значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel не позволяет изменять данные в Request, поэтому необходимо получить параметры запроса и добавить туда то, что Вам необходимо:

```
public function store() {
  $data = array_merge(request()->all(), ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);
  $inivation = Inivation::create($data);
}
```

Если пользователь авторизован, то в `user_id` будет его ID. Если нет, то там будет `null`

P.S. В Вашем случае нет необходимости указывать параметр `Request`